# Spring Boot import one autoconfiguration into another

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-context

I am trying to create a SB3 library that exports auto-configurations.

Here is the simplified scenario:

```
@AutoConfiguration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
// some other conditions
public class TopLevelAutoConfiguration {}

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
public class AdditionalConfiguration {}
```

*META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports*:

```
com.example.TopLevelAutoConfiguration
```

**Question**: How to import `AdditionalConfiguration` into `TopLevelConfiguration`, so that `@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)` is respected?

A simple `@Import` does not respect the condition put on top of `AdditionalConfiguration`, and `@ImportAutoConfiguration` does not seem to have any effect.

Appending `AdditionalConfiguration` to *org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports* works, of course, but I would need to duplicate the conditions from `TopLevelAutoConfiguration` in `AdditionalConfiguration` *in addition to specifying `@ConditionalOnBean`*, which I really don't like.

Comment: replace `com.example.TopLevelConfiguration` by `com.example. TopLevelAutoConfiguration`

Comment: @Numichi this was just a typo, fixed